# Google place picker localization

Tags: android, google-places-api, android-maps-v2

Im using the [google place picker](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/placepicker) inside of my app and if the phone is in language different from english I get different responce from the naming of the place I pick. For example if I pick the country Macedonia and the phone is in english I get the place selected as `Macedonia (FYROM)` but if my phone is for example in Slovenian i get this as a selected country `Makedonija (NJRM)`. Is there a way to always get the places picked on english? Does the google place picker support that?

Comment: you can change the language of the app. Take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/a/2900144/4428183

Comment: You should use Place ID as the GUID for a Place, use the `getId()` method: https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/places/Place#public-methods